# php - Multiple checkbox will check when data load vaild value

Tags: php

I'm writing html,php code. My html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="food[]" value="apple"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="food[]" value="banana"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="food[]" value="something"/>
```

I did get and save the values of multiple checkbox in database. And when i get database:

```
Array([0]=>'apple',[1]=>'banana')
```

My problem is that i want to checkbox is checked if array has value like value of checkbox but i can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render your checkbox like this way as well.

```
<?php 
  $data['food'] = array('apple', 'banana'); //db retrieved value

$foodList = array('apple', 'banana', 'something');

foreach($foodList as $food) {
$checked = in_array($food, $data['food']) ? "checked = 'checked' " : "";
$out = "<input type='checkbox' name='food[]' value='{$food}' {$checked}>";
$out .=$food;
echo $out;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want to be able to make your checkboxes be checked if their value is returned from the database (thats what I understand anyway):

```
<?php
function checkit($queryArr, $val)
{
    # If a value is in the array from the database, add checked attribute
    return (in_array($val, $queryArr))? ' checked="checked"' : '';
}
# Array back from database
$queryArr = ['apple','banana'];
?>

<input type="checkbox" name="food[]" value="apple"<?php echo checkit($queryArr, 'apple') ?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="food[]" value="banana"<?php echo checkit($queryArr, 'banana') ?>/>
<input type="checkbox" name="food[]" value="something"<?php echo checkit($queryArr, 'something') ?>/>
```